# Node.js - Is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm writing a login in Node.js. It used to work just fine, but now I'm trying to add a field and it stopped working and I have no idea why. I'm using Passport.js to do the authentication.

The weird part is that it does add the user to the database, but it switches up the fields. Name is password etc.

The error I'm getting is as follows;

> C:\Users***\Documents\GitHub\Query\config\passport.js:33
>                       return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Je email bestaat al.'));
>                              ^
>
> TypeError: done is not a function
>       at Query. (C:\Users***\Documents\GitHub\Query\config\passport.js:33:28)

passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/login.js');
var configAuth = require('./auth');

module.exports = function (passport) {

    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
            nameField: 'name',
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function (req, name, email, password, done) {

            User.findOne({
                'local.email': email
            }, function (err, user) {

                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Je email bestaat al.'));
                } else {

                    var newUser = new User();

                    newUser.local.name = name;
                    newUser.local.email = email;
                    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                    newUser.save(function (err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }

            });

        }));

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function (req, name, email, password, done) {
            User.findOne({
                'local.email': email
            }, function (err, user) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (!user)
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'De gebruiker bestaat niet. Maak een account!'));
                if (!user.validPassword(password))
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wachtwoord is verkeerd. Probeer het opnieuw!'));
                return done(null, user);
            });

        }));
```

login model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        name         : String,
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    },
    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    } });

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null); };

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password); };

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Routes

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('login.ejs', {
            message: req.flash('loginMessage')
        });
    });

    app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs', {
            message: req.flash('signupMessage')
        });
    });

    app.post('/', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect: '/topic',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true
    }));

    app.post('/register', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect: '/topic',
        failureRedirect: '/register',
        failureFlash: true
    }));

};
```

Form part of the view

```
 <form action="/register" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control nameForm" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <!-- END FORM GROUP -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control emailForm" name="email">
                        </div>
                        <!-- END FORM GROUP -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name="password">
                        </div>
                        <!-- END FORM GRROUP -->
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-default">Registeer</button>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verification callback signature for `LocalStrategy` is incorrect:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        nameField: 'name',
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, function (req, name, email, password, done) { ... })
```

The correct signature:

```
function(req, email, password, done) { ... }
```

(no `name` argument)

That also explains why the fields seem to be shifted.

Comment: ReferenceError: name is not defined on line 38. It's using the name variable in the newUser.local.name=name; line.

Comment: `LocalStrategy` works with two fields: `username` and `password`. You can opt to use an e-mail address instead of a username, which is what you did, but you can't have both. So you're going to have to work around that; since you're passing in `req` you can probably use `req.body.name` instead.

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do though is using the username & password for the auth, but I made an extra field in the view so the user can fill in their name. That way I can show the name on the loggedin page. So I'm just trying the add the extra field to the database. isn't this possible with the Passport? If not I can show the email.

Comment: For Passport's LocalStrategy you can only define two fields that are going to be used for logging in, so you need to choose if that's `e-mail/password` or `username/password`. Those fields you define in the strategy options. However, when saving a new user to the database you can access any other fields that your form has through `req.body`.